# Where can I find the Base64Encoder class?

Tags: java, screen-scraping

Hi I saw an example on StackOverflow which had this code:

```
String encoding = Base64Encoder.encode ("test1:test1");
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://host:post/test/login");
httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

I have a task similar to this. I tried to use the same code but I couldn't find the Base64Encoder class anywhere. Im using httpclient-4.1.2.jar and httpcore-4.1.2.jar. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to have commons codec also to use Base64 encoding with HttpClient. Here is link. [Commons codec link](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)

Answer (score 6):

A [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) en/decoder has long been missing from the Java APIs, so you'll have to find a good 3rd party one, e.g. [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/), [iHarder Base64](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/), etc.

Comment: Actually there's one in the `JAXB` stuff which is actually public and not in an internal package.

Comment: Oh but I like being lazy and now I have to find the link to the exact class and all, but you're right - it's good information, so I'll do that.

Answer (score 2):

Since maerics asked me to:

Since I think Java6 there is actually the [DatatypeConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) class which is part of JAXB.

The two static public methods `parseBase64Binary` and `printBase64Binary` should be of interest. Also note it's defined in `java.lang` so it's an official part of the JDK. You can use it, but personally I like the commons variant better since it doesn't return a string when decoding the base64 stuff..